# What does "Maybe it's a Big Horse I'm Morporkian" mean?

Tags: meaning, terry-pratchett, wordplay, discworld

In Terry Pratchett's book *Raising Steam*, there is an explanation of the phrase "Have seen the big horse" where the author uses the sentence "Maybe it's a Big Horse I'm Morporkian". What exactly does this sentence mean?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is a pun on ‘[Maybe it’s because I’m a Londoner](http://www.songfacts.com/detail.php?id=16923)’, a song written to boost morale during World War II, by Hubert Gregg, but made famous by Flanagan and Allan as an expression of pride in London.

The song can be [heard on You Tube](https://youtu.be/Ln3sidFtIAU) if the Apple Music version on the Songfacts link above isn’t accessible.

Answer (score 17):

It was a 'knock-knock' joke in the 1960s, when **everyone** knew the song.

> Person 1: Knock knock.
> Person 2: Who's there?
> Person 1: M.A.B. is a big horse.
> Person 2: M.A.B. is a big horse who?
> Person 1: [Sings] A-maybe it's a-because I'm a Londoner. . .

Comment: I was too young to know that :D Have an upvote!

Comment: @Spagirl I was too old NOT to!